# How to append next new items in RecyclerView?

Tags: android, spinner, android-recyclerview

I am working on implementing `StaggeredGridView` adapter using `RecyclerView`. How to append the next items fetched from server in RecyclerView with a `Spinner`. I am using following but it's not appending it's overriding the previous data.

```
 mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            visibleItemCount = mStaggeredGridLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mStaggeredGridLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            int[] firstVisibleItems = null;
            firstVisibleItems = mStaggeredGridLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPositions(firstVisibleItems);
            if (firstVisibleItems != null && firstVisibleItems.length > 0) {
                pastVisibleItems = firstVisibleItems[0];
            }

            if (loading) {
                if ((visibleItemCount + pastVisibleItems) >= totalItemCount) {
                    loading = false;
                   ...//  Some Async call to backend
                   AsyncCall.onSuccess(Response response){
                     mAdapter.addItems(response);
                     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

It's not working : `mAdapter.addItems(response)`. Do I need specified the last position in appending items?

How can I load a spinner in between adding `new items` and `scrolldown`?

## Edit

Code for AddItems

```
 public void addItems(List<Model> response) {
    size = response.size();
    model = response;
}
```

## Edit-2

BTW I tried to added this code before AsyncCall.onSuccess:

```
 mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

 mProgressBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ff3c3f41"));
 mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: By spinner you mean an indeterminate progress dialog to imply loading yes?

Comment: Yes, Like Gmail app does to load new items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

You make a layout similar to this, at the bottom you keep the progress bar with visibility gone, when you are loading data from server all you have to do is call setVisibility on the progressbar.

For the first part of your problem just change the code to this. The problem with your code is that even though you call the function addItems its not exactly adding items to your model list but replacing it with the response you should .addAll() function on a list to add items from a list to another list. if you don't have access to the addAll function just iterate over the response list and add each item to the model list.

```
public void addItems(List<Warehouse> response) {
    size = warehouses.size() + response.size();
    warehouses.addAll(response);
}
```

Comment: Great! I am testing it. BTW What I am doing wrong here in first part of the question?

Comment: @user4567 can you post the code for addItems() function?

Comment: I just did. Look at the post please

Comment: @user4567 See answer I posted solution for your first problem too

Comment: Model.size + response.size? I didn't get it. How can you get the size of Model class?

Comment: sorry, i thought model was your list in your adapter. What you should do is add the items from response to whichever variable is the list of items holding the data for your recycler view. Just post the whole code for your adapter and i'll post the fix

Comment: BTW I tried to added `Edit-2` section code but I cannot see progress bar

Comment: Ah! My bad I can see it in some other position. I can fix it. 

Can you help me to figure it out How to append all data? because Model model = new Model and I am getting response as a list. How to append new data (response as a list of model objects) in model (a list of objects)

Comment: If you are using a custom adapter I need to see the code for the adapter and also for the activity with the list view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93445/discussion-between-user4567-and-bhargav).